# Push to Docker private registry from inside a docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-repository

I have a Jenkins docker container which has access to main docker socket by mapping its volume described [here](https://container-solutions.com/running-docker-in-jenkins-in-docker/). so I want to push an image to local docker private registry container which as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/), image should be tagged by host name like this:

```
docker tag ubuntu:16.04 localhost:5000/my-ubuntu
```

localhost is not known inside docker but by using docker gateway ip, docker push image to https and I get this error:

```
+ docker push 172.17.0.1/myalpine
The push refers to repository [172.17.0.1/myalpine]
Get https://172.17.0.1/v2/: read tcp 172.17.0.1:34956->172.17.0.1:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

Any idea of how to make it not use https or other solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the connection insecure, you can edit the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and include the following content in it:

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "172.17.0.1:5000" ]
}
```